# добавить vue в текущий проект gwt

Tags: javascript, vue.js, gwt

Есть проект SPA работает на gwt фреймворке. Ой как я устал с ним разбираться... Точнее учить яву, чтобы оно собрало проект на js... Какая то двойная работа получается...
Вопрос. Конечно проект переделывать это оч много времени займет. Но хотелось бы продолжить работу с более удобным js фреймворком. у меня есть опыт с vuejs думал на нем может.
Вопрос может кто то делал похожее объеденял 2 фреймворка или переходил с gwt работал.
Или это сильно утяжелит сайт.

Comment: GWT чуток устарел и неудобен, особенно для адаптивных интерфейсов. Лучше фронтенд делать на vue.js, а бекенд например на Spring Boot. Отлично сочетаются. Передачу данных между ними можно делать в формате json, используя например библиотеку ky.js на стороне клиента.

Comment: Это да я в идеале так и хотел бы. НО уже  работает код на gwt и чтоб его переделать на vue я по прикидкам оцениваю в год работы постепенной. что не оч по душе. вопрос как лайтово перейти на vue оставив часть кода работать на gwt

Comment: Думаю тут надо будет с сервлетами работать. GWT работает поверх сервлетов, и поэтому можно будет часть запросов маппить на свои сервлеты, на которые обращается клиент на vue.

Comment: вот тут интересный момент. но сходу не пойму о чем речь. может подскажите про что точнее почитать ознакомиться

Comment: Есть много туториалов по работе с сервлетами, они все поверхностные. Если нужно глубже понять, то только официальная спецификация от создателей https://jcp.org/aboutJava/communityprocess/final/jsr369/index.html. Суть в том что адреса url запросов от фронтенда можно раскидать по разным серветам используя шаблоны адресов. Таким образом, новые страницы с запросами от vue можно направлять на новые сервлеты, а старые адреса оставить как есть на сервлете обслуживающем GWT.

Comment: У тебя в проекте в файле web.xml наверное существует уже маппинг адресов на сервлеты для GWT. Просто создаешь независимые от GWT сервлеты, и задаешь для них адреса от фронтенда на vue. То есть фронтенд на GWT обращается к своему сервлету, а vue к независимым сервлетам. Тем более в настройках vue можно указать на каких адресах фронтенда он работает.

Comment: с этим понял. а вопрос. я знаю что gwt он там еще использует  токены авторизации, заголовки. надо наверное это как то для vue прицепить вопрос как проще правильнее ?

Comment: Вообще приложения ориентированные на cloud чаще используют JWT. Но это больше подходит когда люди регистрируются через gmail, vk, facebook  и т.д. Клиент на js берет у них токен JWT и посылает на бекенд в заголовке Authorization . А бекенд просто проверяет токен на валидность с помощью всяких библиотек и сверяет пользователя с базой. Если же без провайдера токенов, то обычно через шифрованные сессии внутри куки и это передается туда обратно, но сервер сам ответственен в этом случае за создание безопасного куки